# Can anybody explain what this simple method is doing, step by step?

Tags: ios, swift

This is part of a calculator program

Creating a boolean type variable with a false value to use for our if statement

```
var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber: Bool = false
```

We put the title of the buttons from 0-9 and made the digit variable value equal the button's titles (0-9)and we want the numbers to display in the label's display that we created but we need the 0 (the title of the first button to be removed from the label's display we created, once we start typing digits)

```
@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton)
{

    let digit = sender.currentTitle!

    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {

        display.text = display.text! + digit


    }
    else {

   display.text = digit


    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true


    }

}
```

Comment: What's the current output? Whats it supposed to be?

Comment: If I'm correct the same examples are explained in an online course / tutorial called Developing iOS 8 Apps with Swift. It's available on iTunes U (the first or second lecture): https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through this step by step.

If you think about how a calculator works, if you are typing a completely new number (say you just got an answer and you want to start with a new equation) the entire bar will be erased in place of the new number you are typing.

But this does not occur every time you are typing a number, otherwise the entire bar would only be able to read a single digit.

Your function is:

```
@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton)
{

    let digit = sender.currentTitle!

    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {

        display.text = display.text! + digit


    }
    else {

   display.text = digit


    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true


    }

}
```

the first line:

```
let digit = sender.currentTitle!
```

sets the variable digit to the current number is being typed by the user.

The next line,

```
 if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
          display.text = display.text! + digit
       }
```

If the user is in the middle of typing a number, the number on screen will append whatever digits the user is typing to the end.

The last part:

```
    else {

   display.text = digit


    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true


    }

}
```

Detects that the user is typing a completely new number (starting a new equation possibly), so the text is completely replaced with the first number the user types

The mode is then set to userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber, so that whatever numbers are following the first one will be appended to the end rather than replacing the entire number.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but how does it know that the user is typing a number, that is simply the name of the variable, and not a method or something?

Comment: It IS just a variable -- but there must be another method that uses your appendDigit function or your userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber boolean (perhaps when the user enters a number)

Comment: ahhh I see, but I'm still confused on the tested condition for the if statement, where it says" If userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber" .....that value for it is false when it was declared.....that part is confusing me....why the need to even use this variable?

Comment: Oh. Because the variable is set to false, the function will always go to  the else portion of your the function first. At the end of the else statement , userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber is set to true, so that any number that is typed after the first one will be appended to the end, thus allowing for numbers to be larger than only 1 digit. This variable is needed to determine if the numbers on screen will be replaced or if they will have numbers appended to the end of them.

Comment: Thank you so much, that really does make sense now, so when the button is pressed it goes down to the else and after that it goes back up to the beginning of the If statement and executes the top portion? because the variable was set to True in the else portion?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially when you click the first number, it sees that and sets the displays text to that single number. Then, every number typed after that is added to the end of the first digit to create a larger number.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck!